# Fit Points With a Smooth Curve

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, computer-vision, scikit-image

I want to fit a set of points on a image with a **smooth** curve in python. The curve may be open or closed. Moreover, I want to get the curve plotted over the image as a mask that has the same size as the image. Is there any modules or functions I can refer to? Thanks.

Comment: Smoothing always implies averaging, in my point of view. So, you will get a smaller number of points. When you use a moving average, data will be missing for the first points. To solve your problem, you would have to do a fit to the data (high-order polynomial? Depending on how your data looks) and then evaluate the fit function for all the points you got in your original curve.

Comment: see approxPolyDp function. Or have a look at (interpolating if necessary) splines.

Comment: @nostradamus Sorry for confusing you. Actually I actually mean connecting a set of points with smooth curves. They are not necessary data points.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally called Parametric Interpolation. There is a scipy function that does just that called [splprep](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html). The steps you are requesting are:

**1)** Smooth a shape (built with ordered points, if not use [convex hull](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) first, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763853/plotting-a-set-of-given-points-to-form-a-closed-curve-in-matplotlib/36764052#36764052)).

**NOTE:** *for more on how to create a shape over an image check* [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103604/extract-image-segment-from-polygon-with-skimage/37149857#37149857).

**2)** Use the smooth shape to build a mask over an image (lets say 2D array).

The following recipe does that:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import path

# Building a shape with scattered points.
x = np.array([10, 10, 0, 0, 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 20, 20, 10]) + 10
y = np.array([0, 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 20, 20, 10, 10, 0, 0]) + 10
image = np.random.randint(0, 10, (50, 50))

# Smoothing the shape.
# spline parameters
s = 3.0 # smoothness parameter
k = 2 # spline order
nest = -1 # estimate of number of knots needed (-1 = maximal)
t, u = splprep([x, y], s=s, k=k, nest=-1)
xn, yn = splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 500), t)

# Showing the original shape
plt.imshow(image.T, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray')
plt.plot(x, y, color='b', linewidth=3)
plt.xlim(0, 50)
plt.ylim(0, 50)
plt.show()

# Showing the original shape vs smooth shape
plt.imshow(image.T, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray')
plt.plot(x, y, color='b', linewidth=3)
plt.plot(xn, yn, color='r', linewidth=3)
plt.xlim(0, 50)
plt.ylim(0, 50)
plt.show()

# Changing values inside the shape (and outside). Building a boolean mask.
image1 = image.copy()
image2 = image.copy()
mask = np.zeros(image.shape)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(image.shape[0]),range(image.shape[1]))
shapes = np.hstack((xn[:, np.newaxis], yn[:, np.newaxis]))
p = path.Path(shapes)
for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
        if not p.contains_point((i, j)):
            image1[i, j] = 0
            mask[i, j] = True
        else:
            image2[i, j] = 0

# Showing changes in image for values outside shape.
plt.imshow(image1.T, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray')
plt.plot(xn, yn, color='r', linewidth=3)
plt.xlim(0, 50)
plt.ylim(0, 50)
plt.show()

# Showing changes in image for values inside shape.
plt.imshow(image2.T, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray')
plt.plot(xn, yn, color='r', linewidth=3)
plt.xlim(0, 50)
plt.ylim(0, 50)
plt.show()
```

The code is commented for you to know what is happening at each of the plots of the results:

[image: Simple Shape over image]
1. *Simple Shape over image*

[image: Simple vs Smooth shape over image]
2. *Simple vs Smooth shape over image*

[image: Use values inside shape]
3. *Use values inside shape*

[image: Use values outside shape]
4. *Use values outside shape*